# To calculate $\nabla f$ and $\nabla f(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I need to calculate $\nabla f$ and $\nabla f(0,0)$, where
$$f(x,y)=10x^3-5x^2+5xy+5y^2+8.$$

My work so far: Using the formula

$$\nabla f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$
I got
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(10x^3-5x^2+5xy+5y^2+8)&=30 x^{2} - 10 x + 5 y,\\
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(10x^3-5x^2+5xy+5y^2+8)&=5x + 10 y.
\end{align*}

Thus

$$\nabla f \left(x,y\right)=\left(30 x^{2} - 10 x + 5 y,5 x + 10 y\right)$$

Is my process correct so far? Also, to calculate $\nabla f(0,0)$, would

$$\nabla f \left(0,0\right)=\left(0,0\right)$$

as $(0,0)$ would provide no values?

Comment: The gradient computation looks correct to me, as much as its value at $(0,0)$. I did not get the *would provide no values* part, though.

Comment: @Ilya Apologies for my vague wording. I just wanted to see how $(0,0)$ values would differ from $(x,y)$ in calculating the gradient for $10x^3-5x^2+5xy+5y^2+8$, or would they be the same?

Comment: Still don't get you. To compute $\nabla f(0,0)$ you first compute it like you did for general $(x,y)$, and then put $x = 0, y = 0$.

Comment: Thanks Ilya for the clarification, regarding how to compute $\nabla f(0,0).$ That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is answered in the comment, let me just briefly summarize:

You have calculated correctly the gradient vector $\nabla f$ using one of the correct  definition. Concerning $\nabla f(0,0)$, it seems to be a confusion in notation. [As pointed out in the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3764769/to-calculate-nabla-f-and-nabla-f0-0#comment7745426_3764769), $\nabla f(0,0)$ means that one first calculate $\nabla f = \nabla f(x, y)$, then evaluate at $(x, y) = (0,0)$. Since

$$ \nabla f \left(x,y\right)=\left(30 x^{2} - 10 x + 5 y,5 x + 10 y\right),$$

we have

$$ \nabla f \left(0,0\right)=\left(30 (0)^{2} - 10 (0) + 5 (0),5 (0)+ 10 (0)\right) = (0,0).$$

Comment: Thanks Arctic Char for the clarification. It now makes sense and I can see now where I went wrong with the confusion in notation.